# Perform operation on each imputed dataset in R's MICE

Tags: r, r-mice

How can I perform an operation (like subsetting or adding a calculated column) on each imputed dataset in an object of class `mids` from R's package `mice`? I would like the result to still be a `mids` object.

**Edit: Example**

```
library(mice)
data(nhanes)

# create imputed datasets
imput = mice(nhanes)
```

The imputed datasets are stored as a list of lists

```
imput$imp
```

where there are rows only for the observations with imputation for the given variable.

The original (incomplete) dataset is stored here:

```
imput$data
```

For example, how would I create a new variable calculated as `chl/2` in each of the imputed datasets, yielding a new `mids` object?

Comment: It would be easier if you took the time to create a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we can offer specific code suggestions. This is a bit too broad and non-specific as is.

Comment: @user20650, it does store the original dataset in `imput$data`, but it's separate from the imputed datasets. I just added an example with this.

Comment: If you want to generate `chl/2` you can calculate this before the imputation. Than when doing the imputation you add the restriction that when any imputation of missing for this column equals `chl/2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to calculate the variables before the imputation and place restrictions on them.

```r
library(mice)

# Create the additional variable - this will have missing
nhanes$extra <- nhanes$chl / 2

# Change the method of imputation for extra, so that it always equals chl/2
# Change the predictor matrix so only chl predicts extra
ini <- mice(nhanes, max = 0, print = FALSE)

meth <- ini$meth
meth["extra"] <- "~I(chl / 2)"

pred <- ini$pred  # extra isn't used to predict
pred["extra", "chl"] <- 1

# Imputations
imput <- mice(nhanes, seed = 1, pred = pred, meth = meth, print = FALSE)
```

There are examples in [mice: Multivariate Imputation by Chained Equations in R](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03).

Answer (score 15):

This can be done easily as follows -

Use `complete()` to convert a mids object to a long-format data.frame:

```
 long1 <- complete(midsobj1, action='long', include=TRUE)
```

Perform whatever manipulations needed:

```
 long1$new.var <- long1$chl/2
 long2 <- subset(long1, age >= 5)
```

use `as.mids()` to convert back manipulated data to mids object:

```
 midsobj2 <- as.mids(long2)
```

Now you can use `midsobj2` as required. Note that the `include=TRUE` (used to include the original data with missing values) is needed for `as.mids()` to compress the long-formatted data properly. Note that prior to mice v2.25 there was a bug in the as.mids() function (see this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158327/69413)

EDIT: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34859264/4269699 (from what is essentially a duplicate question) you can also edit the mids object directly by accessing $data and $imp. So for example

```
 midsobj2<-midsobj1
 midsobj2$data$new.var <- midsobj2$data$chl/2
 midsobj2$imp$new.var <- midsobj2$imp$chl/2
```

You will run into trouble though if you want to subset $imp or if you want to use $call, so I wouldn't recommend this solution in general.

Comment: It appears that the bug in `as.mids` may have been corrected in the most recent release of mice (2.25, 2015-11-09).

Comment: Did this work for you?  Because I have been getting some strange results after using `as.mids`.  More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511909/as-mids-replaces-added-values-with-na

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of `with` that can help you here

```
with(imput, chl/2)
```

the documentation is given at `?with.mids`

Comment: Thanks. But there a way to use this to actually modify each of the imputed datasets, for example by adding the calculated column? `with(imput, function(x) x$imp$new.var=chl/2)` doesn't work, perhaps because the format is wrong.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? `with()` will not work with assignment. But what ever you are running with the `with()` can do the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function for this in the `basecamb` package:

```
library(basecamb)
apply_function_to_imputed_data(mids_object, function)
```