# as.mids replaces added values with NA

Tags: r, r-mice

I need to add variables to imputed data sets built using `mice()` and then use `as.mids()` to reassemble them into a `mids` object for later analysis.  However, when I use `complete()` on the rebuilt `mids` object, I find that many of the values in the new variable added to the dataset have become NA.

```
library(mice)
d1 = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10))
missingness = matrix(as.logical(rbinom(100,1,.2)), ncol = 10)
d1[which(missingness, arr.ind = T)] = NA     #replace some values with NA
d.mids = mice(d1, printFlag = F)             #make the imputations
d.long = complete(d.mids, "long", T)         #extract the original dataset and the imputed ones
added = data.frame(rowSums(d.long[,3:12]))   #make a new column
d.long.aug = cbind(d.long,added)             #add it to the data.frame
d.remids = as.mids(d.long.aug)               #turn it back into a mids object
d.relong = complete(d.remids,"long",T)       #extract it from the mids object
sum(is.na(d.long.aug[11:30,13]))             #0, unless a variable failed to impute due to collinearity
sum(is.na(d.relong[11:30,13]))               #should be the same as  previous value, but almost never is
```

In the above example, I created a new long data.frame and applied `as.mdids()` to it, but I get the same results if I use `cbind` to add the new variable to `d.long`, or if I assign the new variable to `d.long$added`.

How can I make sure that the values in the new variable stay there after I reassemble the `mids` object?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I'm having the same problem. I also tried the alternative method suggested in the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667162/perform-operation-on-each-imputed-dataset-in-rs-mice - but that created other problems

Comment: Actually I fixed it. In my case the operaction I was carrying out to make the new column had a silent bug that was throwing out NA's on occasion!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.  I believe that my solution was to add the variables before imputation, and use passive imputation to calculate them.  I also had to make sure that the imputation of other variables was not based on the added ones.  If I had to go back and do it again, I'd pick a different package like mi or Amelia.