# R - mice - adding a column that sums columns with imputed values

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, r-mice

I have a database with missing data. I need to impute data (I am using mice), then create new columns based on the original columns (using the imputed data). It is these new columns that I need to do my statistical analyses with.

Specifically, my participants filled in several questionnaires using a 7-point likert scale. Some didn't answer all the questions. I need to impute values, then 
    1- sum the values in the columns and have access to this new value for statistical analyses
    2- depending on this sum, divide the participants into "mild, moderate, high" and use this for statistical analyses.

I have based what I am trying to do on this stackoverflow answer:
[Perform operation on each imputed dataset in R's MICE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667162/perform-operation-on-each-imputed-dataset-in-rs-mice)

Here is my code (using R):

```
# Create a sample bdd
bdd=data.frame(
    gender=c("M","F","M", "M", "M", "F"),
    choice=c(1,2,NA,1,1,1),
    gardes=c(0,0,0,5,7,NA),
    EE1=c(3,4,1,NA,3,0),
    EE2=c(2,5,1,3,3,0),
    EE3=c(3,NA,1,5,3,0),
    EE4=c(3,6,1,2,3,0),
    EE5=c(1,4,1,2,3,5),
    EE6=c(3,1,1,3,3,4),
    EE7=c(5,0,1,5,3,5),
    EE8=c(2,6,1,1,3,3),
    EE9=c(3,4,1,6,3,4)
    )

# Create the additional variable - this will have missing values
bdd$EE <- bdd$EE1+bdd$EE2+bdd$EE3+bdd$EE4+bdd$EE5+bdd$EE6+bdd$EE7+bdd$EE8+bdd$EE9

# create ini to get access to meth and pred
ini <- mice(bdd, max = 0, print = FALSE)

# Change the method of imputation for EE, so that it always equals bdd$EE1+...+bdd$EE9
meth1 <- ini$meth
meth1["EE"] <- "~I(bdd$EE1+bdd$EE2+bdd$EE3+bdd$EE4+bdd$EE5+bdd$EE6+bdd$EE7+bdd$EE8+bdd$EE9)"

pred1 <- ini$pred  
# change the predictor matrix so only bdd$EE1-9 predicts EE (necessary?)
pred1[ "EE", ] <- 0 
pred1[ "EE", c("EE1", "EE2", "EE3", "EE4", "EE5", "EE6", "EE7", "EE8", "EE9")] <- 1
# change the predictor matrix so that EE isnt used to predict
pred1[ , "EE" ] <- 0  


# Imputations
imput <- mice(bdd, seed=1, pred = pred1, meth = meth1, m=1, print = FALSE)
```

Please note that this does not work. Any other way to do this elegantly? TIA for any and all advice!!!

Edited to add: this is the error message I get when I try to run this code:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(`1` = c(20L, 14L,  :
    replacement element 1 has 456 rows to replace 2 rows
2: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(`1` = c(20L, 14L,  :
    replacement element 1 has 456 rows to replace 2 rows
3: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(`1` = c(20L, 14L,  :
    replacement element 1 has 456 rows to replace 2 rows
4: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(`1` = c(20L, 14L,  :
    replacement element 1 has 456 rows to replace 2 rows
5: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(`1` = c(20L, 14L,  :
    replacement element 1 has 456 rows to replace 2 rows
```

Here is the bdd I created for this question:

```
      gender choice gardes EE1 EE2 E3 EE4 EE5 EE6 E7 EE8 EE9
1      M      1      0   3   2  3   3   1   3  5   2   3
2      F      2      0   4   5 NA   6   4   1  0   6   4
3      M     NA      0   1   1  1   1   1   1  1   1   1
4      M      1      5  NA   3  5   2   2   3  5   1   6
5      M      1      7   3   3  3   3   3   3  3   3   3
6      F      1     NA   0   0  0   0   5   4  5   3   4
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, would you add a little bit of example data with your missing values? Perhaps just a few rows of `bdd`? It's hard to de-bug code without test data

Comment: Thanks Nate - I am going to do this right away :)

Comment: from a quick glance, dont use your dataframe in the imputation bounds call ie change `"~I(bdd$EE1+bdd$EE2 ...` to `"~I(EE1+EE2...`

Comment: Thank you so much user20650!! Yes, that was my error! I had spent a lot of time trying to figure it out and hadn't seen this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code without the bug, after the correction that user20650 pointed out!

```
    # Create a sample bdd
bdd=data.frame(
    gender=c("M","F","M", "M", "M", "F"),
    choice=c(1,2,NA,1,1,1),
    gardes=c(0,0,0,5,7,NA),
    EE1=c(3,4,1,NA,3,0),
    EE2=c(2,5,1,3,3,0),
    EE3=c(3,NA,1,5,3,0),
    EE4=c(3,6,1,2,3,0),
    EE5=c(1,4,1,2,3,5),
    EE6=c(3,1,1,3,3,4),
    EE7=c(5,0,1,5,3,5),
    EE8=c(2,6,1,1,3,3),
    EE9=c(3,4,1,6,3,4)
    )

# Create the additional variable - this will have missing values
bdd$EE <- bdd$EE1+bdd$EE2+bdd$EE3+bdd$EE4+bdd$EE5+bdd$EE6+bdd$EE7+bdd$EE8+bdd$EE9

# create ini to get access to meth and pred
ini <- mice(bdd, max = 0, print = FALSE)

# Change the method of imputation for EE, so that it always equals bdd$EE1+...+bdd$EE9
meth1 <- ini$meth
meth1["EE"] <- "~I(EE1+EE2+EE3+EE4+EE5+EE6+EE7+EE8+EE9)"

pred1 <- ini$pred  
# change the predictor matrix so only bdd$EE1-9 predicts EE (necessary?)
pred1[ "EE", ] <- 0 
pred1[ "EE", c("EE1", "EE2", "EE3", "EE4", "EE5", "EE6", "EE7", "EE8", "EE9")] <- 1
# change the predictor matrix so that EE isnt used to predict
pred1[ , "EE" ] <- 0  


# Imputations
imput <- mice(bdd, seed=1, pred = pred1, meth = meth1, m=1, print = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please note that I am not 100% sure that the code for changing the predictor matrix is correct. If you wish to use this code, please double check that first. Thanks!